# [edit]How can I rewrite my URL with .htaccess according to these needs?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

ThI've tried some configurations with my `.htaccess` file but I really can't find out what is going wrong.

I am new to the .htacces file and i just want 1 simple rewrite.

How do I rewrite this:

- my pages are in my `~/Pages` folder
- I don't want to show: `http://host.com/Pages/page.php`
- I want to rewrite this to: `http://host.com/page`
- and that for example `~/Pages/Folder/page.php` becomes: `http://host.com/Folder/page`

Also I want it possible that people can navigate without having to think about capital letters in the URL bar.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
ok i have the extension removed. now i'm trying to point to ~/Pages/index.php
When someone visits the url http://HOST.com/index

This is what i got so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /urenreg/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !urenreg/Pages/
RewriteCond ^(.+?)?$ Pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)?$ /$1.php [L]
```

problem: it keeps pointing to /urenreg/pages and doesn't enter the file name in the link (suspecting)

Comment: Just move your pages folder into the domain root folder? :P then just use a program like notepad++, control F > find in files > replace all /Pages/... with /

Comment: @danielsmile: He also wants to remove php extension...

Comment: @Chococroc he probably also wants a bacon sandwich, but i wont be the one to give it to him

Comment: use a cms. You get to define everything yourself. i'd suggest zend or if you're not known with programming something like drupal or wordpress

Comment: Note you've misspelled ".htaccess" as ".htacces" - Apache won't read a misspelled configuration file.

Comment: @Dylan Westra: Post your .htaccess and we'll be able of checking what is going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i ended up.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /urenreg/

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/urenreg/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /urenreg/$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !lib/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dist/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !grunt/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !less/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !test-infra/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !urenreg/Pages/
RewriteRule (.*) Pages/$1/ [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

for example

Move your .php files from:

```
public_html/*.php
```

To:

```
public_html/gta/*.php
```

What happens is that you're accessing:

```
http://domain.com/gta/about
```

And it tries to find the .php file at:

```
http://domain.com/gta/about.php
```

Given that all files are on the folder gta you .htaccess can be what you exactly have, but needs to be on the public_html folder and there should be NO .htaccess inside the gta folder:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: aa problems in my ssl configuration. it works now to remove the file extension thank you :)